# MySQL Limit by URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the following to limit my table output by a ?limit=10 within my URL however it is giving me:

```
 ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
 ( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in     C:\wamp\www\sql_table.php on line 44
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  250584  {main}( )   ..\sql_table.php:0
2   0.0020  258904  mysql_fetch_array ( )   ..\sql_table.php:44
```

My code is as follows:

```
    if ($_GET['limit']) {
$limitsql = ' limit 0, ' . $_GET['limit'];
} else
$limitsql = '';

// This chooses which results i want to select from
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE 1" . '$limitsql');
```

Comment: What is this? (Table Name) change it with your actual table name, and please stop using deprecated function as `mysql_*`, learn about pdo or mysqli instead. Your code is also vulnerable to mysql injection

Comment: print your final SQL, the one you runs in the mysql_query.
Your solution can provide some sql injections, so be aware too

Comment: also WHERE 1 is not needed here(this is not error).

Comment: i will sort the sql injection out once i have the code working as i will use sql escape commands where needed.

Comment: do a print_r($result) and see what that gives.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic this has sorted the error thank you just need to work out now why it is not limiting

Comment: print_r($result) gave me Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp\www\sql_table.php on line 40

Comment: as @KeesSonnema said,print sql command string. For example: $sql_string = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE 1" . '$limitsql';  $result = mysql_query($sql_string); echo $sql_string;

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: mysql_query is returning FALSE because the query is failing. You should be testing if the query succeeded or failed

Comment: i do not use mysqli as i have been told not to by my employer so this is not out of choice

Comment: Btw I hope this is not production code, because this is a hacker's dream.

Comment: @user2452069, you have interesting employer :D

Comment: @BojanKovacevic my employer is teaching me the basics of php mysql. Once i have the basics i will move to sqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE 1" . '$limitsql');
```

To This:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE 1" . $limitsql);
```

Also, you really should not put input from `$_GET` directly into SQL.

Comment: WHERE 1 is not needed here :)

Answer (score 3):

The primary issue here is that you don't need `$limitsql` to be in quotes, so change it to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (Table Name) WHERE 1" . $limitsql);
```

However, there are a few other things that need attention with this code. Firstly, as mentioned in comments, the mysql_* functions are deprecated, and you should ideally change to another library such as mysqli or PDO.

Also, this code is very vulnerable to sql injection attacks, and the input should be sanitised before putting into an SQL query.

Additionally, you aren't checking the output from your call to `mysql_query`. The error you see is because the function returns `false` when the query fails.

Comment: add an intval to your answer so he wont have sql injection worries from the $limitsql = ' limit 0, '.intval($_GET['please_inject_here']); at line number 2

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array()) {

}
```

However, you should use:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

}
```

You didn't provide the code you use here, so I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($_GET['limit'])
{
$limitsql = $_GET['limit'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0, $limitsql");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if($_GET['limit']){
    if (is_numeric($_GET['limit'])) {
        $limitsql = ' limit 0, ' . $_GET['limit'];
    }
    }else{
$limitsql = '';
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE 1" . $limitsql);
```